# publishing installs, can't select "android only" audience?

Tags: android, facebook, coronasdk

I am unable to select "Android only" when trying to create my audience for app installs, the radio button is disabled, see image below:
[image: disabled android radio button]
I'm using CoronaSDK for creating a game, and i publish the install when the game launches. I have all of the information setup in the App Information page (package name, class name, key hashes are all filled out).

Any idea what could be keeping me from selecting "Android only" as part of my audience?

Comment: Have you also turned on Single Sign On and Deep Linking?

Comment: No, but I don't have either of those elected for the Native iOS App either, and i can select it without an issue.

Comment: Even after enabling both of those, I'm unable to select "Android only" as an ad platform.

Comment: I had found why I can't have "Android only". There is a few things that i did to show the option for "Android only" (But I am not sure which one is the exact solutions for it but the things i did includes:
Downloading the Facebook SDK into the android application, Create Facebook login option, enable "Single Sign On" and "Deep Linking" as well as in the "Advertise on Facebook" Page, select "Android" in the App Platform drop down list and the "Android only" will show up. But I guess we could only use either iPhone or Android but not both together when creating the ads in Facebook

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your development environment is not set up correctly.  I suspect that you haven't downloaded the API Levels needed your project. You need to download that API Level via the SDK Manager too.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Also note that the Android SDK requires the 32-bit version of JDK 6, which is not installed on OS X Mavericks by default, so that could be why if that is the case.